# SQL Server : Select distinct max(date) group

Tags: sql, database, select, distinct

This is my table `offs`:

```
date ----------   oid ------   head -----  cnt

2012-1-9 -----13      --------  10   -----------1
2012-1-11 --- 13      --------  6  -----------  2
2012-1-22 --- 13      --------  10   -----------3
2012-1-22 --- 11      --------  10   -----------4
```

I need a select function with a result the `max(date)` from oid and distinct head, like that:

```
2012-1-11 --- 13      --------  6  -----------  2
2012-1-22 --- 13      --------  10   -----------3
2012-1-22 --- 11      --------  10   -----------4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this query:

```
SELECT a.*, b.cnt from(
SELECT MAX(Date) AS Date, oid, head
from offs group by oid, head
)a inner join offs b on a.Date=b.Date and a.oid=b.oid and a.head=b.head
```

Comment: Sorry it was my fault, cnt is different in my case. If I "group by", I will get all columns.

Comment: Please try this `SELECT a.*, b.cnt from(
SELECT MAX(Date) AS Date, oid, head
from offs group by oid, head
)a inner join offs b on a.Date=b.Date`

Comment: you should join on OID and head as well

Comment: Invalid column name 'Date'. in this case Line 4 "a.Date"

Comment: Okay I joined on oid but don't get not my expected results

Comment: This is what I'am looking for. Could you give me the same result without select cnt?